# How to inherit from textbox and override keypress and keyup events?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, textbox

I want to create a new class inherits from System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and assign keypress and keyup events to my control.

Something like this :

```
    class CurrencyTextbox : TextBox
    {
        private void CurrencyTextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char ch = e.KeyChar;

            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 13)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void CurrencyTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrencyTextbox.Text))
            {
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                Int64 valueBefore = Int64.Parse(CurrencyTextbox.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                CurrencyTextbox.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
                CurrencyTextbox.Select(CurrencyTextbox.Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: SLaks's answer works ! Many thanks to him. Now everytimes I want it I need to drag a textbox from toolbox into form then go to from.Designer.cs to replace "private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextBox1;" to "private CurrencyTextbox TextBox1;". Is there any way to add it to toolbox so I can use it like other controls.

Comment: I try to return the text of the currency textbox as number format. Eg : textbox2.text = currencytextbox1.text (currencytextbox1.text=999,999) then I would like textbox2.text = 999999 (no ","). I tried to override text get method but the app then crashed. Do you have any idea for it ? Thank in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should override the `protected virtual void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)`.
Make sure to call `base.OnKeyUp(e)`, or the event will not be raised.

You can also add a regular event handler by writing `KeyUp += CurrencyTextbox_KeyUp`

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Now everytimes I want it I need to drag a textbox from toolbox into form then go to from.Designer.cs to replace "private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextBox1;" to "private CurrencyTextbox TextBox1;". Is there any way to add it to toolbox so I can use it like other controls.

Comment: After you build your project, it should appear in the toolbox.  If it doesn't, check the toolbox options tab.  Also, try making the class `public`.

Comment: Thank SLaks, I try to return the text of the currency textbox as number format. Eg : textbox2.text = currencytextbox1.text (currencytextbox1.text=999,999) then I would like textbox2.text = 999999 (no ","). I tried to override text get method but the app then crashed. Do you have any idea for it ? Thank in advance !